# How to get an frame as an Image from the Recorded Video -AVFoundation (Image as a thumbnail)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I want to extract an image from the recorded video . I was using this code m but no results , Image is not showing up.

**I am using the code below for doing this task**

```
AVURLAsset* asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoPath] options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator* imageGenerator = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:asset];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1) actualTime:nil error:nil]];
[videoFrame setImage:image];
```

Please help with a code use to extract image from recorded video

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
    NSURL *videoURl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURl options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    generate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
    NSError *err = NULL;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 60);
    CGImageRef imgRef = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
     UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];
    [videoFrame setImage:img];
    [img release];
```

Comment: I tried this way but nothing result shows up when i do this 
    UIImageView *images =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
    [images setImage:_imageFirst];

    [self.view addSubview:images];

Comment: It works ... actually i was doing the mistake , i was removing the video URL path from the memory before this code . Now everything worked perfetly

Answer (score 0):

Use this method for generating thumbnail:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark THUMBNAIL GENARATION
- (UIImage*)testGenerateThumbNailDataWithVideo:(NSURL *)videoURL {

    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *gen = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    gen.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, 600);
    NSError *error = nil;
    CMTime actualTime;

    CGImageRef image = [gen copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];
    UIImage *currentImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image];
    CGImageRelease(image);

    return currentImg;
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I tried this way also , it makes an image and shows its address too
Printing description of images->_storage:
<UIImage: 0x1c569cc0>

but doesn't display anything

Comment: ok got it , it works now , Actually i wrote a line before the code which is removing the video path from memory it works

Comment: Curious why you made the time `CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, 600);` not `CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, 60);` like @SAMIR RATHOD answer?